# Agile manifesto principle not understood

Tags: agile, agile-processes

what is the intention of this:

> Simplicity--the art of maximizing the
>   amount of work not done--is essential.

Comment: "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler." - Albert Einstein (paraphrased)

Comment: "There is nothing so useless as doing efficiently that which should not be done at all." - Peter Drucker

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Among other things, it means that a team can spend an amazing amount of time building a complex system that will handle all possible eventualities - or it can do only what is needed right now, get it right, and get it out the door.

The KISS principle is related - keep the program simple, it will be easier to write, easier to maintain, and out the door faster.

Answer (score 18):

You might prefer:

> Simplicity -- the art of minimizing the amount of work done -- is essential.

Basically, this just means cutting out needless effort wherever possible, including within your own agile process.

Answer (score 13):

This translates to:

> Always do the simplest thing that does the job required.

As developers we're often tempted to come up with a gold-plated solution that does 101 cool things as well as what is required. This usually takes longer, and will likely be harder to maintain in future. So always do the simplest thing that will actually work.

Answer (score 3):

The Agile manifesto is about project management.

A non-Agile project is filled with work, much of which is a waste of time.

Complex plans and status reports are work, but they have little real value.

Some design documents, walkthroughs and reviews are work, but they create very little value.

Some quality assurance activities are done simply to demonstrate that code will -- eventually -- get done.  This is a lot of work to prove that progress will happen in the future.

Non-Agile ("Waterfall") projects are filled with work that is of very little real value.

The Agile manifesto suggests we **not** do all of this low-value work.

Answer (score -3):

its a definition of simplicity
simplicity:

The Art of (it means Simplicity is an art, if U can think in simple way U can handle ur job Well)

the amount of work not done (U want to handle ur job with a lot of things and doing a lot of works -- above sentence reminds U to do not Do all of the jobs, Do only the essential Jobs)

To maximizing: simplicity can help u to maximize the above sentence, it means that minimize ur job with less cost & time.

Comment: This can hardly be read, and seems not to answer the question.

Comment: You should use complete words.. Avoid "U", "ur"